# How can I create an effective platform collision detection in AS3?

Tags: collision-detection, collision, actionscript-3

I'm trying to do puzzle game, still starting getting the basics done first, such as collision detection, camera, movement, and so forth.

But I've been having some trouble making the platforms behave as they should.

While using hitTestObject, I've coded each platform to stop the player from falling once it hits it.

The problem is that the player can enter inside a platform by the sides and stop from falling as it is touching the platform.

Is there a rigidbody or something in AS3 that can make flash think of my platforms as solid objects?

Comment: Could you post some code? It's super hard to help based on what we know so far.

Comment: There are plenty of existing solutions out there. Search more and don't get bogged down reinventing the wheel (unless you want to).

Comment: I didn't understand the problem. Player entering platform from the side - is it what you want or not?

Comment: you should just use box2d as3. there's even ports for starling and so.